# SWT java - painting with GridData and GridLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm trying to paint a shell (actually, a tab with composite) that will look like in the image I attached. 
I tried almost everything for each widget - GridData, GridLayout, tried to change the horizontal spanning and num of columns but nothing comes up as I need... :(

I tried using this link http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm
but with no success.

Can anyone please guide me?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a good starting point for you:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    Composite radioLeft = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    radioLeft.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, false));
    radioLeft.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button(radioLeft, SWT.RADIO);
        button.setText("Radio " + i);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    }

    Composite radioRight = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    radioRight.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));
    radioRight.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button(radioRight, SWT.RADIO);
        button.setText("Radio " + i);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    }

    Group groupLeft = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    groupLeft.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, false));
    groupLeft.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        Label label = new Label(groupLeft, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("Something " + i);
        label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    }

    Group groupRight = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    groupRight.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    groupRight.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false));

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Label label = new Label(groupRight, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("Something " + i);
        label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    }
    Group bottom = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, false));
    bottom.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        Label label = new Label(bottom, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("Something " + i);
        label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    }

    Composite buttonComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    buttonComp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
    buttonComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Button left = new Button(buttonComp, SWT.PUSH);
    left.setText("Left");
    left.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    Button right = new Button(buttonComp, SWT.PUSH);
    right.setText("Right");
    right.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!shell.getDisplay().readAndDispatch())
            shell.getDisplay().sleep();
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]